# How to make a BarChart/PieChart with input data on it

Tags: android

I am creating an app with a barChart/pieChart . and my idea is i want the user to input their data on the EditText Provided . and my problem is i dont know how to do that  can anyone help me with this for my proj. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

u can use mp chart library or achart engine library 
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine

this libraries r good for chart with animation

Comment: thanks for the reply . i just look to that link that you gave me . and i dont get any solution or i am just confuse but .i need is a step by step on how to do that . because i already have my chart .

Comment: which chart engine ur using?, so i can help according.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library easy to use MpAndroidChart
[a link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Try Google charts as well 
[a link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) very interactive and responsive

Comment: i google it but suddenly all the answers that i got is not the solution that i want . but thanks for the reply though.

Comment: You want to take input from the user ryt so take input and put them in an array and then set those values to these chart objects. If this is not the solution kindly elaborate it bit more.